# Get Status of Driver Inside Visual Basic

Tags: drivers

I'm currently trying to detect which drivers appear as "not working" in visual basic.

[This unknown device is a good example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7ZQR.png) of what I'm trying to grab (notice how it has the flag DN_HAS_PROBLEM).

I've tried using searches such as:

```
Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( "root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemDriver")
```

And running a loop in the searcher.Get() through [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394472(v=vs.85).aspx)

However, none of these seem to return what I am looking for.

Would anyone happen to know how I can get the DN_ statuses within Visual Basic?

Thanks!

Comment: It'd be helpful to see that loop code you attempted so we can see what you may have done incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Win32_SystemDriver class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394472(v=vs.85).aspx) lists these `Status` properties:

> ```
> OK
> Error
> Degraded
> Unknown
> Pred Fail
> Starting
> Stopping
> Service
> Stressed
> NonRecover
> No Contact
> Lost Comm
> ```

...whereas `DN_HAS_PROBLEM` comes from the [CM_Get_DevNode_Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538514(v=vs.85).aspx) function, or perhaps also from other system calls.

There may not be a way to get that specific code from the API *you're* using, but perhaps the existing `Status` properties will suffice for your needs if you don't need to know more specific failure reasons.

If you *do* need to know that specific status, you'll have to call other APIs, like the one I called out.